# Sort two Laravel objects in the correct order

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 Eloquent objects that i want to "merge" so to speak.

I dont know if merging is the best approach please come with suggestions.

```
$customer = Customer::find($customerId);

$events = $customer->Events()->Unfinished()->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

$notes = $customer->Notes()->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Events() is a hasMany = $customer->hasMany('events');

Unfinished() is a scope = $query->where('status', '=', '0');

Notes() is a hasMany = $customer->hasMany('notes');

I want to merge `$events` and `$notes` together so that i can loop through these with created_at falling the correct order.

Lets say $notes contains 2 posts:

```
note 1
    created_at: 2013-01-30 00:00:00
note 2
    created_at: 2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

And $events contains 2 posts:

```
event 1
    created_at: 2014-02-01 00:00:00
event 2
    created_at: 2014-01-02 00:00:00
```

I want them falling like this:

```
event 1
    created_at: 2014-02-01 00:00:00
note 1
    created_at: 2013-01-30 00:00:00
event 2
    created_at: 2014-01-02 00:00:00
note 2
    created_at: 2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

How would I best approach this?

Comment: I've something like this where i wanna order results from 2 tables on the created_at. I try to use union to combine them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497865/sorting-union-queries-with-laravel-4-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union dident work unless the two tables has the same columns.
But I did found this answer:
http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#299-319

```
$customer = Customer::find($customerId);

$events = $customer->Events()->Unfinished()->get();

$notes = $customer->Notes()->get();

$combined = $events->merge($notes);
```

edit:
And to sort the combined collection:

```
$combined = $combined ->sortBy(function($sort){
    return $sort->created_at;
})->reverse();
```