# Laravel - Union + Paginate at the same time?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

**Brief:**

I am trying to union 2 tables `recipes` and `posts` then add `->paginate(5)` to the queries.

But for some reason I get this error:

> Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a
>   different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from
>   `posts`

**Code:**

```
$recipes = DB::table("recipes")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "description", "created_at")
                    ->where("user_id", "=", $id);

$items = DB::table("posts")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at")
                ->where("user_id", "=", $id)
                ->union($recipes)
                ->paginate(5)->get();
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Without `->paginate(5)` the query works fine.

Comment: Encountered this problem. Try to use `->simplePaginate(n)` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, pagination cause problem. Right now, you can create a view and query the view instead of the actual tables, **or** create your `Paginator` manually:

```
$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$paginate = 5;

$recipes = DB::table("recipes")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "description", "created_at")
            ->where("user_id", "=", $id);
$items = DB::table("posts")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at")
            ->where("user_id", "=", $id)
            ->union($recipes)
            ->get();

$slice = array_slice($items->toArray(), $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
$result = Paginator::make($slice, count($items), $paginate);

return View::make('yourView',compact('result'));
```

Comment: Thanks! how would you add orderBy to the union query? i tried to add it after the ->union but the "order by" ends up within one of the parentheses (version 4.2.8).

Comment: The solution is right but for small amounts of data.

Comment: In order to get a large amout of data, it is a bad solution. Because `->get` will get all data, then slice the array.

Comment: It is not actually the solution but just virtual pagination to make the users happy.

Comment: can't believe this is accepted answer lol

Comment: This will not work for large tables

Answer (score 8):

I faced this kind of issue already. I found a thread also not about `pagination` but about `unions`.

Please see this link : [Sorting UNION queries with Laravel 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497865/sorting-union-queries-with-laravel-4-1)

@Mohamed Azher has shared a nice trick and it works on my issue.

```
$query = $query1->union($query2);
$querySql = $query->toSql();
$query = DB::table(DB::raw("($querySql order by foo desc) as a"))->mergeBindings($query);
```

This creates an sql like below:

```
select * from (
  (select a as foo from foo)
  union
  (select b as foo from bar)
) as a order by foo desc;
```

And you can already utilize Laravel's `paginate` same as usual like `$query->paginate(5)`. *(but you have to fork it a bit to fit to your problem)*

Comment: great answer, I am build spesific group by (exlude null and zero index) in merged 2 table union, this way working paginate and ordering.

Answer (score 7):

Reiterating [jdme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4481235/jdme)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258814/7506439) with a more elegant method from `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

```php
$recipes = DB::table("recipes") ..
$items = DB::table("posts")->union($recipes) ..

$query = DB::query()
    ->fromSub($items, "some_query_name");

// Let's paginate!
$query->paginate(5);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow Johnny! thank you so much, it works for me fine, after a day of struggling with similar issue)) Does it mean it will work fine if we have a lot of data, right??

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works great for Query Builder.

But here's my approach for Laravel Eloquent Builder.

Assume that we're referring to same Model

```
$q1 = Model::createByMe();       // some condition
$q2 = Model::createByMyFriend(); // another condition

$q2->union($q1);
$querySql = $q2->toSql();

$query = Model::from(DB::raw("($querySql) as a"))->select('a.*')->addBinding($q2->getBindings());

$paginated_data = $query->paginate();
```

I'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: I can't hold myself to say... Superb!

Comment: Useful when I don't want to miss my model as it has appended props.

Answer (score 2):

> **order by**

```
 $page = Input::get('page', 1);

 $paginate = 5;

 $recipes = DB::table("recipes")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "description", "created_at")
                ->where("user_id", "=", $id);
$items = DB::table("posts")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at")
            ->where("user_id", "=", $id)
            ->union($recipes)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->get();

$slice = array_slice($items, $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
$result = Paginator::make($slice, count($items), $paginate);

return View::make('yourView',compact('result'))->with( 'result', $result );
```

View page :

```
   @foreach($result as $data)
  {{ $data->your_column_name;}}
 @endforeach 

  {{$result->links();}}   //for pagination
```

> its help to more peoples.. because nobody cant understand show data in
>   view page  union with pagination and orderby .. thank u

Comment: Loading all the rows in php and then slicing them is not very efficient, especially for large tables.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is too late. But I want to share my problems and my solution.

## My problems:

1. Join with many tables at the same time
2. UNION
3. Paginate (Must use, because I have to use a common theme to show pagination. If I made own custom for pagination, it will not match to current. And in the future, a common theme may be changed.)
4. Big data: view took 4 seconds, page load took 4 seconds => total is 8 seconds. (But if I set condition inside that view, it was least than 1 second for total.)

## Query

※This is the sample.
MariaDB, about 146,000 records.

```
SELECT A.a_id
     , A.a_name
     , B.organization_id
     , B.organization_name
  FROM customers A 
    LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)

UNION ALL

SELECT A.a_id
     , A.a_name
     , B.organization_id
     , B.organization_name
  FROM employees A 
    LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)
```

## Solution

[Reference from www.tech-corgi.com](https://www.tech-corgi.com/laravel5-6-union%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AEpagination/) (やり方２), I updated my PHP code to filter inside my query, and then call paginate normally.

I must add a condition (filter) before getting large records. In this example is **organization_id**.

```
$query = "
    SELECT A.a_id
         , A.a_name
         , B.organization_id
         , B.organization_name
      FROM customers A 
        LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)
     WHERE 1 = 1
       AND B.organization_id = {ORGANIZATION_ID}

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.a_id
         , A.a_name
         , B.organization_id
         , B.organization_name
      FROM employees A 
        LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)

     WHERE 1 = 1
       AND B.organization_id = {ORGANIZATION_ID}
";

$organization_id = request()->organization_id;
$query = str_replace("{ORGANIZATION_ID}", $organization_id, $query);
```

But it still cannot be used in **paginate()**. There is a trick to solve this problem. See below.

### Final code

Trick: put query inside `()`. For example: `(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A)`.

Reason: **paginage()** will generate and run Count query `SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A)`, if we did not put **inside brackets**, Count query would not be a correct query.

```
$query = "
    ( SELECT A.a_id
         , A.a_name
         , B.organization_id
         , B.organization_name
      FROM customers A 
        LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)
     WHERE 1 = 1
       AND B.organization_id = {ORGANIZATION_ID}

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.a_id
         , A.a_name
         , B.organization_id
         , B.organization_name
      FROM employees A 
        LEFT JOIN organizations B ON (A.organization_id = B.organization_id)

     WHERE 1 = 1
       AND B.organization_id = {ORGANIZATION_ID}
    ) AS VIEW_RESULT
";

$organization_id = request()->organization_id;
$query = str_replace("{ORGANIZATION_ID}", $organization_id, $query);

$resultSet = DB::table(DB::raw($query))->paginate(20);
```

Now I can use it normally:

1. SELECT, JOIN, UNION
2. paginate
3. High performance: Filter data before getting

Hope it help!!!

Comment: Exactly the best answer, and the only right one.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the total count for pagination is the problem here. This is the error I got when used `$builder->paginate()`

```
"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `institute_category_places` where `status` = approved and (`category_id` in (3) or `name` LIKE %dancing class% or `description` LIKE %dancing class% or `address_line1` LIKE %dancing class% or `address_line2` LIKE %dancing class% or `city` LIKE %dancing class% or `province` LIKE %dancing class% or `country` LIKE %dancing class%) and `institute_category_places`.`deleted_at` is null) union (select * from `institute_category_places` where `status` = approved and (`category_id` in (3, 4) or `name` LIKE %dancing% or `description` LIKE %dancing% or `address_line1` LIKE %dancing% or `address_line2` LIKE %dancing% or `city` LIKE %dancing% or `province` LIKE %dancing% or `country` LIKE %dancing% or `name` LIKE %class% or `description` LIKE %class% or `address_line1` LIKE %class% or `address_line2` LIKE %class% or `city` LIKE %class% or `province` LIKE %class% or `country` LIKE %class%) and `institute_category_places`.`deleted_at` is null))"
```

If you want to paginate without total count you can use

```
$builder->limit($per_page)->offset($per_page * ($page - 1))->get();
```

to get only set of rows in the page.

Getting all the rows and counting total is memory inefficient. So I used following approach to get total count.

```
    $bindings = $query_builder->getBindings();
    $sql = $query_builder->toSql();
    foreach ($bindings as $binding) {
        $value = is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'" . $binding . "'";
        $sql = preg_replace('/\?/', $value, $sql, 1);
    }
    $sql = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $sql);

    $total = DB::select(DB::raw("select count(*) as total_count from ($sql) as count_table"));
```

Then we have to paginate the result manually.

```
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $per_page = 15;

    $search_results = $query_builder->limit($per_page)->offset($per_page * ($page - 1))->get();

    $result = new LengthAwarePaginator($search_results, $total[0]->total_count, $per_page, $page, ['path' => $request->url()]);
```

If you can use raw sql queries, it is much more CPU and memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Eloquent**

I adapted [jdme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4481235/jdme)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258814/880719) in order to use it with Eloquent. I created a class extending the default Eloquent Builder and overiding the `union` method to fix the issue with paginate.

Create `app\Builder\BuilderWithFixes.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Builder;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class BuilderWithFixes extends Builder
{
    /**
     * Add a union statement to the query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Closure  $query
     * @param  bool  $all
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
     */
    public function union($query, $all = false)
    {
        $query = parent::union($query, $all);
        $querySql = $query->toSql();
        return $this->model->from(\DB::raw("($querySql) as ".$this->model->table))->select($this->model->table.'.*')->addBinding($this->getBindings());
    }
}
```

In you Model (for example `app\Post.php`), include the method `newEloquentBuilder` below to replace the default Eloquent Builder with `\App\Builder\BuilderWithFixes`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Eloquent as Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    // your model stuffs...

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new \App\Builder\BuilderWithFixes($query);
    }
}
```

Now you can use union + paginate at the same time within your model (in this case `Post`) normally, like:

```
$recipes = Recipe::select("id", "title", "user_id", "description", "created_at")
                 ->where("user_id", "=", $id);

$items = Post::select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at")
             ->where("user_id", "=", $id)
             ->union($recipes)
             ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and unfortunately I couldn't get the page links with `{{ $result->links() }}`, but I found another way to write the pagination part and the page links appears

[Custom data pagination with Laravel 5](http://psampaz.github.io/custom-data-pagination-with-laravel-5/)

```
//Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
$collection = new Collection($searchResults);

//Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
$perPage = 5;

//Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
$currentPageSearchResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();

//Create our paginator and pass it to the view
$paginatedSearchResults= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($collection), $perPage);

return view('search', ['results' => $paginatedSearchResults]);
```

Answer (score 0):

for paginate collection do this:

add this to boot function in \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
  /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
```

From hereafter for all collection you can paginate like your code

```
$items = DB::table("posts")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at")
                ->where("user_id", "=", $id)
                ->union($recipes)
                ->paginate(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

For those who may still look for the answer, I have tried `union` and `paginate` together and got **right result** under laravel **5.7.20**. This will be better than merging collections then paginate which will not work on big amount of data.

Some demo code (in my case, I will deal with multiple databases with same table name):

```
$dbs=["db_name1","db_name2"]; 
$query=DB::table("$dbs[0].table_name");
for($i=1;$i<count($log_dbs);$i++){
    $query=DB::table("$dbs[$i].table_name")->union($query);
}
$query=$query->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(50);
```

I haven't tried on other higher version of laravel. But at least it could work now!

**More information**

My previous version of laravel is 5.7.9 which will report the `Cardinality violation` error. So the laravel team solved this issue in some version of 5.7.x.

Answer (score -2):

```
$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$paginate = 5;
$recipes = DB::table("recipes")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "description", "created_at")
            ->where("user_id", "=", $id);
$items = DB::table("posts")->select("id", "title", "user_id", "content", "created_at") ->where("user_id", "=", $id)->union($recipes)->get()->toArray();
$slice = array_slice($items, $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
$result = new Paginator($slice , $paginate);
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers. Your answer may or may not be a correct answer, but it is in the moderation queue after being marked as "low-quality". Please take a moment to improve your answer with an explanation.