# Laravel Shorter or Cleaner Code and safer way of Joining table form multiple database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I have tried to **Join tables** from multiple database, below is my code I was just wondering if there is another or shorter way and best & safer approach in constructing my code.

```
$variable = Mymodel::join('database1.table1 as t1','t1.id','=','database2.table2.t1_id')->get();
```

And is it possible in Laravel to have relationship(1to1,1tomany,manytomany) of two table with a different database? Or only join method is the only way to connect them? If possible can please give some example thanks.

Comment: Have a time to read this documentation from laravel https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Here are some discussions regardint to the use of query builder, union and pagination. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338456/laravel-union-paginate-at-the-same-time/58118253#58118253

Comment: how bout the multiple database is the approach same for all table?

Comment: If you read [table conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) there's a way to define a custom table name for your model. This custom name can be `database2.table2` if you need the model to be read from a different database schema. The rest is just Laravel boilerplate